# How do I make Rigid Body Joints not become loose due to weight?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

In BGE I have a Ragdoll made up of Rigid Body Objects connected by Rigid Body Joints. When I stand it up and make it stay standing up and press play, the weight on the upper arms is a lot even though I lowered it beyond what it naturally should be (below image is exaggerated to show it), and makes it stretch, ignoring its limits! Also the more motion I apply via Logic Bricks the more they go past their rotation limits too.

I know I can make a balljoint/hinges mechanism that doesn't allow them to pass objects of course but that is a lot of work.

[image: [![See the upper arm gets a lot a pull and the RBJs hang if heavier]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WOj6.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WOj6.jpg)

Comment: Can you share your setup? How have you linked the joints - what type of Rigid Body Constraint did you use?